# I accidentally exited vim with :x!~ and now my ~ shows up in a different path

Tags: shell, filenames, rm, special-characters, tilde

When exiting a file as root, I typed `:x!~` and hit enter. Now I have the following:

```
root@host:/etc/shinken/services$ ll
total 64K
-rw-r--r--  1     0     0  515 Sep  1 18:24 ~
drwxr-xr-x  2 10003 10003 4.0K Sep  1 18:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 10003 10003 4.0K Aug  8 17:11 ..
<other files omitted>
```

If I `cd ~`, it takes me to `/root` as expected.
How can I delete the new `~` without accidentally deleting my *actual* home?

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /etc/shinken/services
rm ./~
```

Not much to say about that really.  By specifying `./` in front of `~` you stop the shell from performing tilde expansion, and it will be treated as the name of a file in the current directory.

Another option would have been

```
cd /etc/shinken/services
rm '~'
```

or just

```
rm /etc/shinken/services/~
```

---

In Vi and Vim, `:x` will work like `:wq` and write the file before quitting. By appending a filename (`~` in this case), the file with the given name will be written.  The difference between the two commands is that `:x` only writes the file if the current buffer has been modified since the last save.  The `!` overrides writing to a read-only file.

Comment: oh... right.... duh.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -- '~'
```

The single quotes around the `~` stop bash from expanding the path and simply passes it to `rm`.

`--` stops rm from interpreting any more arguments as flags and assumes they are all files (no so important in this case but useful if you have a file with a leading `-`).

You can test this with `ls` first.

```
ls -- '~'
```

For example in a directory that does not contain a literal '~' you would get

```
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
```

Showing that `ls` has received the path unmodified.